# Between dates Oracle from c# using Oracle.dataaccess client

Tags: c#, oracle

I have used the below query to access the data from Oracle `all_objects` view. When trying the same from Oracle SQL Developer it work fine and from C# code it is not fetching any data.

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME,OBJECT_TYPE,CREATED,LAST_DDL_TIME
FROM sys.all_objects
where object_type='TABLE'
AND OWNER='SYS'
AND LAST_DDL_TIME between to_date('01/01/2013','DD/MM/YYYY')
  and to_date('01/10/2016','DD/MM/YYYY')
```

If I use the below query without any filter it works fine in both Oracle and from C# as well...

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME,OBJECT_TYPE,CREATED,LAST_DDL_TIME FROM sys.all_objects
```

Any idea that why it is not working?

Below are the sample value that is passed in the getDatSet function, Dates are select from c# DateTimepicker

strFromDate - {2/15/2012 12:00:00 AM}
strToDate   - {11/15/2016 2:31:48 PM}

```
        public DataSet GetDataSet(DateTime strFromDate, DateTime strToDate, List<string> strObjects)
    {
        OracleCommand objCmd;
        OracleDataAdapter objDA;
        DataSet objDS;
        string StrSqlObjects = string.Empty; ;

        try
        {
            StrSqlObjects += " SELECT OBJECT_NAME,OBJECT_TYPE,CREATED,LAST_DDL_TIME FROM sys.all_objects where ";
            StrSqlObjects += " LAST_DDL_TIME between to_date(:startdate,'DD/MM/YYYY') and to_date(:enddate,'DD/MM/YYYY')";

            objCmd = new OracleCommand(StrSqlObjects);
            objCmd.Connection = m_Conn;
            objCmd.Parameters.Clear();
            objCmd.Parameters.Add("startdate", strFromDate);
            objCmd.Parameters.Add("enddate",strToDate);

            objDA = new OracleDataAdapter();
            objDA.SelectCommand = objCmd;

            var oracleCommandBindByNameProperty = objCmd.GetType().GetProperty("BindByName");
            oracleCommandBindByNameProperty.SetValue(objCmd, true, null);


            objDS = new DataSet();
            objDS.Tables.Add("AllChange");
            objDA.Fill(objDS, "Allchange");
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error GetDataSet " + e.Message);

            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseConnection();
        }
        return objDS;
    }
```

Comment: Please show us your full C# code.

Comment: Why do you think it's the date filter, rather than object type or owner? What are those bind variables set to? I suspect they're either not set at all, or are perhaps the wrong case. If those are actually correct, then does your unfiltered query actually show any matching records for the owner/type in that date range? And are you actually providing fixed dates, or ar those bind variables too - again, if so, what are their actual values?

Comment: Just for the purpose of posting I have made date as hard coded value, otherwise it is a binding variable. Even though it is hard coded it is not working

Comment: @Jey - what about the other two bind variables - what are their values, and how are you setting them? As asked already, please edit your question to show your C# code.